# Insert no MySQL não executa

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tendo problemas no SQL ao fazer uma pequena inserção no DB.
Tenho uma tabela com 4 campos:

```
id_match -> int
id_usuario1 -> int
id_usuario2 -> int
situation -> varchar(5)
```

Quando faço a seguinte inserção, não entra no BD:

```
INSERT INTO match VALUES(NULL, '$usuario1', '$usuario2', 'open')
```

O que está errado?

Comment: qual erro que apresenta ?

Comment: @wryel Rodando na aplicação não apresenta erro nenhum, mas rodando no SQL do phpMyAdmin:
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match VALUES (null, '5', '0', 'open')' at line 1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O teu erro deve-se ao facto de [match](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/keywords.html) ser uma palavra reservada. Significa isto que, para que para seja utilizada como um identificador (nome de coluna ou tabela, por exemplo) ela precisa de um tratamento especial.

Pelo teu comentário vi que já conseguiste resolver o problema. Fica, no entanto, aqui a resposta para referência futura.

```
INSERT INTO `match` VALUES(NULL, '$usuario1', '$usuario2', 'open')
```

Para utilizar uma palavra reservada como nome de tabela, coluna ou indentificar um índice podes usar uma de duas soluções;

- Utilizando acento grave "`", ou
- Se o ANSI_QUOTES no SQL mode estiver activado podes usar aspas
  (")

Comment: Valeu pela explicação @bruno.
Eu cheguei a procurar por palavras reservadas em linguagem sql no google, mas não encontrei nada referente a match.
Mas valeu muito pela dica.

Comment: Sem problema @GustavoSevero. A palavra match na minha resposta tem um link para uma lista das palavras reservadas no MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Faça assim que deve funcionar:

```
INSERT INTO match VALUES(NULL, 5, 0, 'open')
```

Você está tentando gravar *strings* um colunas do tipo `int`. Não é possível.

Com a edição parece que é um código PHP, então o correto seria algo assim:

```
INSERT INTO match VALUES(NULL, $usuario1, $usuario2, 'open')
```

Mas não posso garantir porque falta informação sobre o código PHP.

Finalmente existe um erro no nome da tabela. Pelo comentário adicionado abaixo ficou claro qual era o erro. O AP resolveu "escapando" o nome da tabela que é uma palavra reservado do SQL. Desta forma:

```
INSERT INTO `match` VALUES(NULL, $usuario1, $usuario2, 'open')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/Type.sql).

Comment: esses dados estão em variáveis... É possível fazer isso?
INSERT INTO match VALUES(NULL, $variavel1, $variavel2, '$variavel3')?

Comment: Olha o erro que apareceu no phpMyAdmin, @bigown:

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match VALUES(NULL, 5, 0, 'open')' at line 1"

Comment: Se estão em variáveis, a sua pergunta está errada. É possível fazer o que você quer mas tem que ver todo o contexto. Agora você está falando que é algo totalmente diferente do que está na pergunta. O certo era até remover esta pergunta mas ainda dá tempo de você arrumar ela e colocar tudo como efetivamente você está usando.

Comment: Veja se agora o comando está certo na pergunta @bigown

Comment: Olha! Fiz uma pequena alteração no script sql que funcionou, mas até agora não entendi como, pois NUNCA, NUNCA tive que fazer isso.
Tive que colocar " ` ", crase, antes e depois do nome da tabela:

INSERT INTO `match` VALUES(NULL, '$usuario1', '$usuario2', 'open')